# DataGrid with multiple headers

Tags: wpf, templates, datagrid, header, row

I have a DataGrid filled with data. What I would like to do is modifying the template of a particular row in order to display both the row and a new header. For example:

```
Header 1 | Header 2 | Header 3
Data   1 | Data   2 | Data   3                               (row 1)
Data   1 | Data   2 | Data   3                               (row 2)
Header 1 | Header 2 | Header 3 | Header 4 | Header 5         (row 3)
Data   1 | Data   2 | Data   3 | Data   4 | Data   5         (row 3)
Data   1 | Data   2 | Data   3                               (row 4)
```

[Here is a screen shot illustrating my needs.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXcsH.png)

Is there a way to achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: Is it always row(3) the third row that should have headers and data?

Comment: No, it can be any row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a way to achieve what I was trying to do:

I set the DataGrid.ItemTemplateSelector property with a Selector derived from DataTemplateSelector. In the SelectTemplate() method of this selector, I return null for a normal row (to apply the default template), otherwise I create and return the DataTemplate (dynamically, thanks to XamlReader) corresponding to the special row. This template is composed of a DataGrid. The ItemsSource property of the DataGrid is set using a converter (row data converted into an object list).

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to create the following:

[image]

If I understand correctly, in this case, you must use a nested `DataGrid`. This effect can be achieved by `DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate -> your DataTemplate`. Also, the pattern should be "normal" `TextBlock`, so it shows some value when nested `DataGrid` hidden. Checks will be carried out using `DataTrigger` in `DataTemplate`.

XAML code:

```
    <DataGrid Name="SimpleDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowHeaderWidth="0" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" Loaded="SimpleDataGrid_Loaded">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="1.5*" Header="HeaderWithDataGrid" IsReadOnly="False">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <!-- Nested DataGrid -->
                            <DataGrid Name="InsertedDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowHeaderWidth="0" Loaded="InsertedDataGrid_Loaded">
                                <DataGrid.Columns>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="InsertedHeader1" Width="1.5*" Binding="{Binding Name}" IsReadOnly="False" />
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="InsertedHeader2" Width="1.5*" Binding="{Binding Age}" IsReadOnly="False" />
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="InsertedHeader3" Width="1.5*" Binding="{Binding Name}" IsReadOnly="False" />
                                </DataGrid.Columns>
                            </DataGrid>

                            <!-- Simply value, if nested DataGrid will be Hidden -->
                            <TextBlock Name="SimpleValue" Text="{Binding Age}" Visibility="Hidden" />
                        </Grid>

                        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                            <!-- It checks for Hidden NestedDataGrid -->
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ShowInsertedGrid}" Value="Hidden">
                                <Setter TargetName="InsertedDataGrid" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                <Setter TargetName="SimpleValue" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <!-- Simply column -->
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="SimpleHeader" Width="1.5*" Binding="{Binding Name}" IsReadOnly="False" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Listing of Person class:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name
    {
       get;
       set;
    }

    public int Age
    {
       get;
       set;
    }

    // For clarity using string. 
    // In real project using a bool.
    public string ShowInsertedGrid
    {
       get;
       set;
    }
}
```

Two `ObservableCollection` for DataGrid's:

```
private ObservableCollection<Person> DataForDataGrid = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
private ObservableCollection<Person> DataForInsertedDataGrid = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
```

In handler `Loaded` event set data for main DataGrid:

```
    private void SimpleDataGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataForDataGrid.Add(new Person()
        {                
            Age = 2,
            Name = "Nick",
            ShowInsertedGrid = "Hidden", // Hidden NestedDataGrid
        });

        DataForDataGrid.Add(new Person()
        {
            Age = 1,
            Name = "Sam",
        });

        DataForDataGrid.Add(new Person()
        {
            Name = "Kate",
            Age = 15,
            ShowInsertedGrid = "Hidden",  // Hidden NestedDataGrid
        });

        SimpleDataGrid.ItemsSource = DataForDataGrid;            
    }
```

`Loaded` event handler for NestedDataGrid:

```
    private void InsertedDataGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid MyDataGrid = sender as DataGrid;

        DataForInsertedDataGrid.Add(new Person()
        {
            Name = "Bob",
            Age = 15,
        });

        DataForInsertedDataGrid.Add(new Person()
        {
            Name = "SpanchBob",
            Age = 151,
        });

        MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = DataForInsertedDataGrid;
    }
```

For beauty and for improving the appearance using the `Styles`.

**EDIT:**

If you want your Nested `DataGrid` was on the whole *Row*, then I can suggest the following solution (not the fact that it is the best solution, but I can only offer this):

[image]

For each cell will use DataTemplate. Therefore `SimpleHeader` transformed into:

```
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="1.5*" Header="SimpleHeader" IsReadOnly="False">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <!-- Nested DataGrid -->
                            <DataGrid Name="InsertedDataGrid2" AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowHeaderWidth="0" Loaded="InsertedDataGrid2_Loaded">
                                <DataGrid.Columns>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="InsertedHeader4" Width="1.5*" Binding="{Binding Name}" IsReadOnly="False" />
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="InsertedHeader5" Width="1.5*" Binding="{Binding Age}" IsReadOnly="False" />
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="InsertedHeader6" Width="1.5*" Binding="{Binding Name}" IsReadOnly="False" />
                                </DataGrid.Columns>
                            </DataGrid>

                            <!-- Simply value, if nested DataGrid will be Hidden -->
                            <TextBlock Name="SimpleValue" Text="{Binding Name}" Visibility="Hidden" />
                        </Grid>

                        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                            <!-- It checks for Hidden NestedDataGrid -->
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ShowInsertedGrid}" Value="Hidden">
                                <Setter TargetName="InsertedDataGrid2" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                <Setter TargetName="SimpleValue" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Where `InsertedDataGrid2_Loaded` you set the data:

```
    private void InsertedDataGrid2_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid MyDataGrid = sender as DataGrid;

        DataForInsertedDataGrid2.Add(new Person()
        {
            Name = "Bob2",
            Age = 215,
        });

        DataForInsertedDataGrid2.Add(new Person()
        {
            Name = "SpanchBob2",
            Age = 251,
        });

        MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = DataForInsertedDataGrid2;
    }
```

For each column using `DataGrid`, and the code you load data for it. Hence, calculate the total number of columns for the main and nested `DataGrid`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It's almost exactly what I want to achieve. The only thing is that you add a nested DataGrid in a single cell while I need to add the nested DataGrid in an entire row.

Comment: Thank you for the edit but indeed this is certainly not the best solution and not the behavior that I need. Thanks anyway!